# how to check if the inputted email has "@" on it

Tags: html

i have a text field for email which is set to required, i want it to show a text that you need to include "@" on your email. like how it displays "fill out this field" when you  pressed the button without typing anything on the field. How can i do it? Thanks.

```
 EXAMPLE:
     <input type="text" name="email" required>
```

Comment: if you are using html5 you can use the type "email" and is automatically checked. either, y think you should use javascript to check it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to use the `type` in case you are using HTML5 as:

```
<input type="email" name="email" required>
```

If you are not using the HTML5 then you need to use some scripting language like Javascript to check the validity. For example in Javascript it would be like:

```
if(!document.getElementById("email").checkValidity())
```

In case of PHP it would be like

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check it by using (since HTML5):

```
<input type="mail" name="email" required>
```

It will display a warning if format is not correct (tooltip, or red color around the field, depending on your browser.

Or you can check it on the server side, once you form is sent. For example with PHP, you can use [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.filter-var.php)

Answer (score 2):

Use pattern attribute,

```
<input type="text" name="email" pattern=".*[@]+.*" />

<input type="email" name="email" required />
```

More details are at: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: ok i'll already did but i have to wait for 3 minutes. i don't know why :) thanks anyway. i'll mark it as accepted

Comment: You don't need to put the `pattern` in case you are using the `type` as `email`. That's unnecessary!

Comment: pattern is useless here

Comment: Also in case of `text` attribute the regex will fail for many of the email address pattern which are invalid. For example `test.@@gmail.com` is not a valid email address but the pattern will pass it :) Not trying to make a fuss, just a nit pick.

Comment: Rahul Tripathi's answer is better, more exact and more precise

Comment: @grasisgThat's not the problem. There will be other persons who will have the same problem than you later, and they should read the pther answer because it's more efficient